# Floated image with variable width and heading with background image

Tags: css, image, css-float, background-image

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;}
        .article {width:600px;}
        .image_container {float:left;margin-right:10px;}
        h1 {height:50px;line-height:50px;background:url(left.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
        h1 span {display:block;padding:0 10px;background:url(right.png) no-repeat top right;}
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="article">
            <div class="image_container">
                <img src="test.jpg" alt="test_img" />
            </div>
            <h1><span>Test heading</span></h1>
            <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            </p>
            <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            </p>
            <h1><span>Test heading</span></h1>
            <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            </p>        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can check out a demo here: http://easwee.net/floated_img_article/

**Problem:**
The image can have 2 different widths (3:2 ratio - horizontal or vertical). The heading has a background image, as you can see, which goes behind the floated image.

Is there a **css solution** to make the background image start where heading text starts - so that it won't get overlapped by the floated image? The left rounded corners need to be visible.

P.S.: You can also point me to a javascript solution but I'd prefer to solve this with css.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Maybe you can create a mock-up of what you mean by "make the background image start where heading text starts"?

Comment: Are you able to detect which image size is going to be on the page before you display the page?

Comment: There already is a demo link attached to the question - the problem can be seen there. I managed to make the heading background-image position itself properly by applying overflow:hidden to h1. However another trick is that paragraphs still calculate padding and margins from behind the border. If you add overflow:hidden to p elements they will get cleared right under the image which leaves a blank space untill the p tag ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to determine which image ratio (3:2 vs. 2:3) before spitting out the page, you can assign a class to the h1, then handle it with CSS margins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;}
        .article {width:600px;}
        .image_container {float:left;}
        h1 {height:50px;line-height:50px;background:url(left.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
        h1.wide{margin-left:260px}
        h1.narrow{margin-left:385px}
        h1 span {display:block;padding:0 10px;background:url(right.png) no-repeat top right;}
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="article">
            <div class="image_container">
                <img src="test.jpg" alt="test_img" />
            </div>
            <h1 class='wide'><span>Test heading</span></h1>
            <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            </p>

            <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            </p>
            <h1><span>Test heading</span></h1>
            <p>
                There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
            </p>        
        </div>
    </body>
```

Then, just switch between `<h1 class='wide'>` and `<h1 class='narrow'>`

Comment: Yes, but that would require javascript to read the image widths and than assign classes.

Comment: That is why I asked above whether or not you could detect it before hand. The class could be assigned server-side if you are using some sort of template.

Comment: I will probably have to do it with javascript since it is work related and dates are not fun. But still I wonder if this issue could be solved with plain css. The catch is that in case you also apply padding to the p it also won't show up since it is calculated from behind the image. And setting a margin would offset all paragraphs and i cannot do :first-child since i do not know how many p will be at the begining wrapping around image. So far overflow:hidden on h1 and p did the best result but still not exactly what i needed.