# How do I flow a ul around a floated img

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an img floated to the left followed by a long ul that should render to the right of the img then continue below it.  It does this, but the portion of the ul next to the img it all left aligned and loses its indentation.

Here is a minimum case example. (also in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/afugab/edit#javascript,html))

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left"><img src="http://i410.photobucket.com/albums/pp190/FindStuff2/Photography/Winter/winter.jpg" width="200" height="150" /></div>
    <ul>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Level 2</li>
                <li>Level 2</li>
                <li>Level 2</li>
                <li>Level 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 1</li>
        <li>Level 1</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"><!-- --></div>
    More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content More content 
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What URL?  I want the ul to flow around the image, and render with the proper indentation.

Comment: Your indentation is actually there but it is calculated from the body - the floated image div covers your margin/padding on nested ul. I've been looking for a solution to this for a long time now but can't seem to find one. What get's behind the floated element can be a background-image, padding or margin. Here's a test case - I posted it one on SO but haven't gor a solution in over a year except for JS http://www.easwee.net/floated_img_article/ .

Comment: This was the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456137/floated-image-with-variable-width-and-heading-with-background-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* add some margin-right for some white space between the list and image */
div {margin-right:12px; float:left;}

/* add overflow and set the list-style attributes */
li {overflow:hidden; list-style:inside square none;}
```

Comment: You rock the party that rocks the party!

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
div {margin:0 10px 5px 0; float:left;}


ul{
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
}
```